# How to Hide a button on one page and show that button on different page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two buttons of type="submit" one for submitting to the database and other for updating the database and for the same purpose I got two PHP files one for submitting and other for updating.

The problem is that I want to hide update button on fist.php and show the submit button and vice-versa.

Comment: Since there are two pages, why not just change the `display` of that button in the css in each page?

Comment: I suppose you need to use some javascript

Comment: Why do you even put a button on a page where you don't want to have it? Your question seems to be lacking some background information.

Comment: Thanks, but earlier there only one button in use and by clicking on it the page get tranferred to update.php but with that both query get executed so I think by using your suggestion it will solved out things.

Comment: My html form is link with submit and update so that the reason both should work correctly.

Comment: By using css it will be easier Thanks , but is there any way to use a single button. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is some logic in the page so that you can know which page to go, right? then you only need one button, in the button's onclick event, you call a javascript function, in which you do your logic check, then change the form's action attribute, then submit the form.

Comment: display will not work because my html form is posting data to update.php by doing it the button will remain hidden in both.

Comment: Adding some code snippets would be helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the page, which has the two buttons you mentioned, send a request to query existing record.
If no record found, the page is supposed to submit to "submit" page, else to "update" page.

Then, in your code, you can put a hidden input element, which contains the value, by which you know where to submit.
maybe something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="direction" value="" display="hidden">
```

Then, you have a button, not a type=submit, but a type=button.
something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
```

Then you have a javascript function. something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function submitForm(){
    if(document.getElementById("direction").value=="submit"){
        //Change form1 to your real form name.
        document.form1.action="submit.php";
        document.form1.submit();
    }else if(document.getElementById("direction").value=="update"){
        //Change form1 to your real form name.
        document.form1.action="update.php";
        document.form1.submit();
    }else{
        alert("error happened. the direction unknown, unable to submit the form");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: My form is posting to update.php and by using upper code My problem is not satisfied of displaying different button in different php file.

Comment: So, you have two buttons and two php files?  Then just put the button into the php file you want, what's your problem? Not knowing which button to put into which php file?